# Twitter API with OAuth2

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use Twitter API, I followed directions of http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/
I installed all the required items, when i test it I get 17 errors.
When i try to import twitter it gives me:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 65, in <module>
import oauth2 as oauth
ImportError: No module named oauth2
```

I have looked at various questions on this topic, but none of them work for me or maybe because I am doing something wrong. Very lost since it seems i installed all the right files and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `easy_install` bypassed all the problems I experienced with dependencies and installation

Comment: had the same issue on ubuntu, used easy_install and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have oauth2 installed in your python environment?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/

Perhaps also look into the python-oauth2 package for your OS? ([Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-oauth2/) | [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/python-oauth2) | [Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/python-oauth2?_csrf_token=8dcebc90e3cd0bc2e47f04fef4558c02999ff57c))

Comment: Yes i had it installed via python setup.py install, that didnt work either. I installed all dependencies httplib, simplejson needed for twitter module as well. It is absolute mystery for me.
I am working on Windows 7, using python 2.7 and downloaded 2.7 files.

Comment: Can you verify this by launching `python` from a terminal and typing `import oauth2`?

Comment: Thanks guys, but i solved it the problem by using easy_install. When I used that it cause no problems, aside from 17 errors in test but twitter module works!